# Insert PDF into Word results in pixelation/blurriness on Windows, but not MacOS?

Tags: pdf, image-quality, pixelation, windows

When I try to place pdf files (created by Adobe Illustrator or elsewhere) into a Microsoft Word document, then on my Macbook Pro Laptop, I can simply drag and drop the file into a word document. This results in a very crisp and high resolution placement of the pdf file in the word document. The image below is a screenshot of a part of the pdf file after placing it into Word on MacOS.

[image]

On my Windows PC, however, I cannot drag and drop pdf files into the Word document. This would only result in placing a pdf file icon into the word document. Instead, I need to import the pdfs by clicking on "Insert" tab, then on "Object", and then "Create from File", and then I choose the file via "Browse".  The result is very awful, however. After import into Word, the pdf file looks very pixelated. See part of a screenshot below after importing into Word on Windows 10.

[image]

**Please advice how I can import pdfs into Word so they get rendered in high quality on Windows PC.**

PS: I tried other import formats into Word on Windows incl. SVG, EMF and WMF, but none of them gives a perfect result.

Note: cross-posted on https://community.adobe.com/t5/illustrator/insert-pdf-into-word-results-in-pixelation-blurriness-on-windows-but-not-macos/td-p/12008811

Comment: Word isn't really a tool designers use for importing images. PDF works better on the Mac because the Mac is build around PDF. I'd try and RGB PNG for Word, regardless of OS. In spite of what MS will tout.. raster formats such as PNG just work better in their (horrible) software.

Comment: My experience with vector formats in Word on Windows is – don’t bother. It won’t work properly. Make a hi-res raster image and use that instead. Or, if you’re going to eventually export a PDF anyway once you’re done writing, just make sure to do the export on a Mac where it works.

Comment: Paste your vectors into power point than un group and re copy and paste into word they are now native MS vectors that have no problems. Anyway PDF works, but the preview is not as nice as the print. Provided that you dont trigger rsterisation by menupulating the file which is easy. ANyway I dont use word much.

Comment: Export from Illustrator as EMF (Enhanced MetaFile). Now, click and drag into a Word document. In my experience EMF generally works fine, although TBH I actually don't use MS Word these days. It's horrible software, even on Windows.  It works perfect in LibreOffice however.  Perhaps it's something you should take up with Microsoft.  Tech support is generally off-topic here.

Comment: @BillyKerr EMF is among the file formats listed as already tried – and my experience agrees. Even EMF, which is supposed to be a native format, rarely works properly.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. Conversion to EMF or SVG results in changes of the pdf file (some of the line art is represented thinner, and some of it is thicker compared to the original). I guess in the end the best solution might be rasterization of the pdf? What do you think about TIF format? And do you think 600dpi will be enough for print and electronic distribution?

Comment: In my experience, Word files are unacceptable for commercial printing. Doesn't matter what resolution you use.

Comment: @Scott What is a better alternative?

Comment: Well, as long as you can export a proper PDF from Word (PDFx), a PDF. Most designers don't even bother with Word and use Indesign, QuakXpress, heck even Scribus for layout. The #1 issue with Word is that any layout can **change** when the exact same Word file is opened on a new system.

Comment: @Scott: What about writing long reports where you have lots of text and here and there supporting graphs (available as high quality pdf files) that need to be inserted?
From what I see Indesign, QuakXpress etc... are mainly for a few pages bit not really long text documents? I tried LibreOffice, but it has the same issue as MS Word on a Windows PC.

Comment: AJ.. Indesign and Xpress are **industry standard** and used for everything from leaflets to 1000+ page manuals. Any application with "Office" in its name is not something designers really use - MS Office, LibreOffice, OpenOffice..et. al. These are all **text editors** not layout tools.

Comment: @AJZ203 i wouldnt even bother with indesign unless my document is atleast 10 pages long. And yes i compile technical raports in indesign all the time. Although i do separate semantics from the style so i write and reference images in something much loke the markup stackexhange uses then generate trough indesigns xml importer a rough autolayout.

Comment: @AJZ203 Scott and joojaa have already more or less said this, but it’s almost the reverse of your impression: InDesign, QuarkXPress, Affinity Publisher, etc., are often used for posters or flyers, but at the core, they are apps especially geared towards laying out longer documents. They have vastly superior functions for creating master pages and text variables and other things that are vital to laying out books, reports, manuals and such things, and which are a real pain to deal with in programs like Word. They are a very different way to work, but very powerful tools.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, you have the OneNote app. Open your PDF file in OneNote for printing. Copy the opened file and then paste in your word document. It will retain the full resolution